# Flutter ios build error caused from deprecated libraries

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, build

I'm using cloud mac server for releasing in ios. And before changing my mac, i succesfully finished build of my ios app, but then i changed my mac server, now when i try to build, getting error below, what can i do to fix this issue, as i understand it's about deprecated libraries, but i can't delete them all because im using them in my app.

```
/Users/user191346/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_analytics-7.0.1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAnalytic
    sPlugin.m:49:19: warning: 'setScreenName:screenClass:' is deprecated: Use +[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:kFIREventScreenView
    parameters:] instead. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [FIRAnalytics setScreenName:screenName screenClass:screenClassOverride];
                      ^
    In module 'FirebaseAnalytics' imported from
    /Users/user191346/Desktop/rate_prof/rate_prof/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:22:
    /Users/user191346/Desktop/rate_prof/rate_prof/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/Headers/FIRAnal
    ytics.h:128:5: note: 'setScreenName:screenClass:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(
        ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/user191346/Desktop/rate_prof/rate_prof/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/System/Library/Framework
    s/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/System/Library/Framework
    s/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/System/Library/Framework
    s/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/usr/include/Availability
    Macros.h:183:64: note: expanded from macro 'DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE'
                #define DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(s) __attribute__((deprecated(s)))
                                                                   ^
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/user191346/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_analytics-7.0.1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAnalytic
    sPlugin.m:49:19: warning: 'setScreenName:screenClass:' is deprecated: Use +[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:kFIREventScreenView
    parameters:] instead. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [FIRAnalytics setScreenName:screenName screenClass:screenClassOverride];
                      ^
    In module 'FirebaseAnalytics' imported from
    /Users/user191346/Desktop/rate_prof/rate_prof/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase/Firebase.h:22:
    /Users/user191346/Desktop/rate_prof/rate_prof/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/Headers/FIRAnal
    ytics.h:128:5: note: 'setScreenName:screenClass:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(
        ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/user191346/Desktop/rate_prof/rate_prof/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics-prefix.pch:2:
    In module 'Foundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/System/Library/Framework
    s/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/System/Library/Framework
    s/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/System/Library/Framework
    s/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk/usr/include/Availability
    Macros.h:183:64: note: expanded from macro 'DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE'
                #define DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(s) __attribute__((deprecated(s)))
                                                                   ^
    1 warning generated.
    building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Users/user191346/Desktop/rate_prof/rate_prof/ios/Flutter/App.framework" failed: No
    such file or directory (2)
    done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needn't delete these packages, just follow these
commands and try in your terminal;

**First Method for fix the issue:**

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```

if isn't work you can try this:
**Second Solution:**

```
flutter pub get 
cd ios
pod install
```

Or you can remove `Podfile.lock` and after try this:

```
cd ios
pod install
```

Comment: Second solution is worked but having another issue, will open seperate question for it, thanks again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66203670/command-phasescriptexecution-flutter-error Here's the other issue, be really glad if you can take a look.