# Command PhaseScriptExecution Flutter error

Tags: ios, flutter, build

I'm using cloud mac server for releasing in ios. And before changing my mac, i succesfully finished build of my ios app, but then i changed my mac server, now when i try to build, getting error below, what can i do to fix this issue, i tried solutions from duplicates of this error but none of them worked for me.

**ERROR**

```
building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Users/user191346/Desktop/rate_prof/rate_prof/ios/Flutter/App.framework" failed: No
    such file or directory (2)
    done

    sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
    total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
    rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at
    /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-54.120.1/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
```

Comment: I think you can create a new flutter project and try it works or not, if it works successful you can cut the lib folder from your another file and paste here so mean replace, and if you have used packages and assets you can cut and paste here also. So configure everthing make sure everything must to work and fix some syntax errors if you have and try run.

Comment: i actually solved it with turning back older github commit, yet thanks for help